# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string - Perl Issue

Tags: regex, perl, syntax-error, perl-module, logical-operators

I am posting this for the 1st time. I have gone through similar issues in the forum, but still I am not able to determine why I am getting this error.

Here is a sample code which I am trying to make..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($m, $b) = @ARGV;
my $count_args = $#ARGV + 1;
my $times = 2**$m;
main();

sub main {
     if ( $m =~ /^\d+$/ ) {
         if ( $b =~ /^and$/i ) {
             func_and();    
         }   else {
             print " not supported\n";
         }
     }   else {
         print " enter valid number of pins\n";
     }
}
sub func_and {
    my $bit;
    for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $times ; $i++ ) {
        my $p = sprintf( "%0${m}b", $i );    
        print "$p\t";
        my @c = split( '', $p );             
        my $result = 3;                      
        foreach  $bit (@c) {
            if ( $result < 3 ) {
                $result = $result && $bit;    
            } else {
                $result = $bit;    
            }
        }
        print "result for AND operation on $bit is $result \n";
    }
}
```

if i give the input as `perl AND.pl 2 and`

The error I get is `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at NAND.pl line 34`.
is there any other way to declare the $ bit variable? and how can one initialize this?
Thanks

Comment: Your last print is probably misplaced as it use `$bit` and if the inner-most `for` don't loop (i.e empty `@c`), `$bit` is not initialized.

Comment: This cannot be the program that you ran to get that error as it contains only 35 lines.

Comment: @RC. It does not matter if the `for` loop is run or not, the `$bit` is localized inside the loop and does not retain the value after the loop.

Comment: @Borodin that is because I had some spaces before using strict and warnings. the line 47 really points out to the last print statement

Comment: @user3335524: It is as well to post the *real* code that goes with the error message. If you modify the program for publication then run it again an show the proper error message.

Comment: @Borodin here you go Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at NAND.pl line 34. removed all the spaces between the lines.

Comment: @user3335524: Thanks, but that should be in your *question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
print "result for AND operation on $bit is $result \n";
```

to:

```
print "result for AND operation on $p is $result \n";
```

Then, you can localize `$bit` to the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach my $bit (@c) {
```

[perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the
>   variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable
>   is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is
>   therefore visible only within the loop. Otherwise, the variable is
>   implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting
>   the loop.
>   If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses that variable
>   instead of the global one, but it's still localized to the loop.

`$bit` was uninitialized before the loop, so it is still unchanged after the loop.

Comment: This works but I am still not able to understand why is $bit not getting printed even after declaration. Can you please explain that?

Comment: @user3335524 The `for` loop is unable to store a value in `$bit` that extends beyond its scope. After the loop, the old value is restored.

Comment: @toolic so how do i initialize the $bit value before the loop? because that value is bound to change

Comment: @user3335524 In your code you do not use the `$bit` variable at all, besides in the loop and the print. It is unclear what you need it for, really. Did you mean `$m` instead?

Comment: @TLP I only need $ bit to store the 1st value of the incoming "splitted" array and then do a AND function of that 1st value with the 2nd incoming bit and so on..

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about there. You're not doing any of those things with that variable.

Comment: @TLP All i want to do is if i Have say 1010 bit coming in.. I need to split it to 1 , 0 , 1, 0 and then do a logical operation on each of the 1,0,1,0 bit. The reason for $bit is.. in that loop it saves the 1st bit 1 from 1,0,1,0 and then does logical operation on other bits.  i have created a reference point with declaring a result value.. and I need to know where is the 1st time I have to go inside the loop

Comment: @mayhem You're still not doing any of those things with the `$bit` variable. The loop does not save anything, except `$result`.

Comment: @TLP that is true. I am only using it to save the 1st incoming bit.

Comment: @mayhem No, you're not. I'm sorry, there's some kind of deep misunderstanding on your part here. You're not using `$bit` at all, except as a loop variable. You may *think* that you are, but you're not.

Comment: @TLP what is your suggestion in this case then to avoid that variable?

Comment: @mayhem I don't know what you think you are using the variable for, so I am unable to advise you.

Answer (score 1):

The worst solution to this problem is to assign a value to $bit when you declare it.

```
my $bit = 0; # no!!!
```

While this gets around the error message it makes it difficult to find the **logical** error in your code. The warning message "use of uninitialized value..." is one of the most important debugging tools you have. If your code produces many such messages, you should turn your warnings into errors so the program halts at the first warning.

```
use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';
```